# In Laravel what is the difference between use User; and /User

Tags: php, laravel, class

i want to know the difference between

> use User;

and

> /User

in laravel.

In my project i see in a controller say UserController it does this
It adds

use User;

at the top of the controller and in function it uses

> User::find($id);

to get query results.

And some other Controller say CompanyController it does not use

use User;

However it does this

> /User::find($id);

and gets the same result.

I am confused with its usage. Which should i follow, what does each type do, can ayone please explain.

Comment: It's just a namespace. You might want to read about this feature: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `use User;` in combination with `User::find($id);`

When you have the slash in front of it you basically combine the 2 above into one.

**in depth:**

The `User` class (according to your example) appears to have no namespace, yet the file you use it in has one.

In other words, the `User` class is defined in the root namespace.

Normally you can use classes from the root namespace without `use` or `/`, but not when the file you use it in has a namespace.

So you will have to specify the namespace of the object you are trying to use, either with `use User;` or `/User::`

While both act identical, most developers opt to use the `use` variant.

Comment: ok so when i use the use User; is it like pre-loaded into the controller.
and can be accessed by any function inside that controller?

Comment: @ScrappyCocco no, it is not "pre-loaded", it just 'tells' the file that **if** it needs the `User` class, where it should find it

Comment: @ScrappyCocco think of it as a `Table of contents`, once you look for a certain chapter you'l know where to find it, and without it you would have no idea where to find it

Answer (score 1):

Both have same behavior but different to use.

```
Use User;
User::all();
```

is basically a reference to that model class that can be used in any class to get its static methods.

```
/user::all();
```

doesn't need to call the reference, this access the model directly so both are basically same.

IN your case you are making a reference to that model class

```
use User;
User::find(2);
```

it will call model to find the matching user;

where in Company Controller you didn't use any reference to model. you're accessing that model by just '/'. laravel provides this just for ease.